# Updating a Table column based on the value of another table which are not related in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I have two tables which are not directly related, like...

**Table 1**

```
VoucherId  | VoucherDate
-----------+-------------
V001       | 2014-12-09
V002       | 2016-01-10
```

**Table 2**

```
FinYearRef | FromDate   | ToDate
-----------+------------+-----------
Y01        | 2014-07-01 | 2015-06-30
Y02        | 2015-07-01 | 2016-06-30
```

Now I add a column `FRef` to **Table 1**

I want to update that `FRef` column by `FinYearRef` from Table 2 where  `Table1.VoucherDate` is between `Table2.FromDate` and `Table2.ToDate`

Answer (score 0):

Update with Join:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.FRef = T2.FinYearRef
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.VoucherDate BETWEEN T2.FromDate AND T2.ToDate
```

Note that this will update FRef with the last match from T2. If you want the first value then:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET T1.FRef = 
(SELECT TOP 1 FinYearRef FROM TABLE2 
WHERE TABLE1.VoucherDate BETWEEN T2.FromDate AND T2.ToDate)
```